# How to set text-field and retrieve value from it in BootstrapDialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-dialog

I'm using monkey friendly version of Bootstrap modal for dialog boxes using "BootstrapDialog" instead of writing a lengthy code. But i'm not sure how to create text field inside the box, so that i can get value from it and use it in my code similar to "prompt()". Thank You

Comment: post a fiddle with something that you tried. Adding a text box inside a bootstrap div is similar to adding a field in any form. Are you using jQuery as well? See [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals) for examples

Comment: @NikhilTalreja I'm not sure of the attributes inside BootstrapDialog. I'm using jQuery. I'm using bootstrap-dialog.js for minimizing code, instead of writing everything in the form of <div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v4E4S/2/

Main change was to move everything inside the `$(document).ready(function () {`
The questions should be displayed on click of OK button of the modal:

```
$(".modal-footer button").on('click', function () {
        var userName = $("#txtUsername").val();
        displayName(userName);
        displayQuestions(questions, options)
});
```

Comment: Your code works fine.But when dialog pops up, the rest of the code executes automatically. How can i stop that ?

Comment: I think you need to post some sample code or create a fiddle. Its getting unclear as to what you are trying to implement.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modal").modal('show');
    displayQuestions(questions,options);
});
Along with the modal popup the method "displayQuestions" executes automatically, questions and options are array i skipped here because of size constraint. I want the method execute only after dialog fades out.